# TableView Not loading

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, tableview

```
//
//  PracticesViewController.swift
//  COVID 19 Safety
//
//  Created by Rishi Kayathi on 8/15/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Rishi Kayathi. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class PracticesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    
    

    
    var practiceType = "good"
    let goodPractices = practices.good().directions
    let badPractices = practices.bad().directions
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var practicesTable: UITableView!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        practicesTable.delegate = self
        practicesTable.dataSource = self
        practicesTable.register(UINib(nibName: "PracticesTableViewCell", bundle: nil),
                                forCellReuseIdentifier: "practiceCell")

    }
    
    @IBAction func typePractice(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        if let temp = sender.accessibilityLabel{
            practiceType = temp
            print(practiceType)
            
        }
        practicesTable.reloadData()
        
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if practiceType == "good" {
            return goodPractices.count
            
        } else {
            return badPractices.count
        }
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "practiceCell",
                                                 for: indexPath) as! PracticesTableViewCell
        
        
        if practiceType == "good" {
            cell.checkmarkOrCross.image = UIImage(named: "checkmark")
            cell.directions.text = goodPractices[indexPath.row]
            cell.directions.textColor = UIColor.systemGreen
            
            return cell
        }
            
        else {
            
            cell.checkmarkOrCross.image = UIImage(named: "xmark")
            cell.directions.text = badPractices[indexPath.row]
            cell.directions.textColor = UIColor.systemRed
            return cell
        }
    }
    
 
    
    
    
}
```

I checked every part of the code with print functions to make sure it was working. However, the cellForRowAt function is not being called.
goodPractices is an array of strings with 3 entries, badPractices is an array of strings with 2 entries. They return 3 and 2 respectively in the number of Rows in section but for some reason the cellForRowAt function is not being called.

Please advise!

Comment: Are the constraints for tableview properly set in storyboard? Make sure its height is not zero.

Comment: Solved the Question: Remember to check your storyboard elements!

Answer (score 0):

Where do you set the number of section ? Seems it is missing.

Comment: number of sections is 1 by default

Answer (score 0):

Try calling method `practicesTable.reloadData()` in your viewDidLoad() method, at the end, after the delegates have been registered and what not. Sometimes this will work and recall those methods.

Comment: I added this in, unfortunately it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboard, try to link `dataSource` there

[image]